# Как исправить ошибку Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

Как исправить и понять данную ошибку, как мне найти кусок кода где она находится ?

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {code, errno, sqlMessage, sqlState, index, sql}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
> at throwOnInvalidObjectType (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:54931:13)
> at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55858:11)
> at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59137:32)
> at updateHostComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59861:7)
> at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:61499:18)
> at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67230:18)
> at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66388:16)
> at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66301:9)
> at renderRootSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66270:11)
> at recoverFromConcurrentError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65678:24)

Вот что мне пишет консоль при данной ошибке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код формы регистрации

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Register = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [err, setError] = useState(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputs((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post("/auth/register", inputs);
      //navigate("/login");
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.response.data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form>
        <input
          required
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          name="username"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          required
          type="email"
          placeholder="email"
          name="email"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          required
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          name="password"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Register</button>
        {err && <p>{err}</p>}
        <span>
          Do you have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Роут аутендефикации

```
import express from "express";
import { register, login, logout } from "../controllers/auth.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", register);
router.post("/login", login);
router.post("/logout", logout);

export default router;
```

Контроллер авторизации

```
import { db } from "../db.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const register = (req, res) => {
  //CHECK EXISTING USER
  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? OR username = ?";

  db.query(q, [req.body.email, req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length) return res.status(409).json("User already exists!");

    //Hash the password and create a user
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    const q = "INSERT INTO users(`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (?)";
    const values = [req.body.username, req.body.email, hash];

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
      return res.status(200).json("User has been created.");
    });
  });
};

export const login = (req, res) => {
  //CHECK USER

  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

  db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length === 0) return res.status(404).json("User not found!");

    //Check password
    const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(
      req.body.password,
      data[0].password
    );

    if (!isPasswordCorrect)
      return res.status(400).json("Wrong username or password!");

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: data[0].id }, "jwtkey");
    const { password, ...other } = data[0];

    res
      .cookie("access_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(other);
  });
};

export const logout = (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("access_token",{
    sameSite:"none",
    secure:true
  }).status(200).json("User has been logged out.")
};
```

Comment: Судя по всему, вам приходит ошибка 500, и в переменную err записывается объект, который реакт не может отрендерить. Ищите, где приходит объект, указанный в ошибке(code, sqlMessage...)

Comment: {err && <p>{err}</p>} если я убираю эту строку то сайт вылитает при переходе на страницу логина и не записывает данные в БД по какой-то причине